# Constraining a function type with an Idris interface

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I'd like to create a function with type constrained by an interface. My intention is to build a simple monoid solver using `VerifiedMonoid` defined in`Classes.Verified` module from contrib package.

Idris gives me the following error:

```
 Monoid-prover.idr line 29 col 5:
 When checking type of MonoidProver.eval:
 Can't find implementation for VerifiedMonoid a
```

for the type signature of `eval`:

```
eval : VerifiedMonoid a => Expr n -> Env a n -> a
```

Am I doing something silly or missing something? Such constrained types (like eval's type) can be interpreted like Haskell's types?

The complete code is shown below.

```
module MonoidProver

import Classes.Verified

import Data.Fin
import Data.Vect

%default total

infixl 5 :+:

data Expr : Nat -> Type where
   Var  : Fin n -> Expr n
   Id   : Expr n
   (:+:) : Expr n -> Expr n -> Expr n

Env : VerifiedMonoid a => (a : Type) -> Nat -> Type
Env a n = Vect n a

eval : VerifiedMonoid a => Expr n -> Env a n -> a
eval (Var i) env    = index i env
eval Id      env    = neutral
eval (e :+: e') env = eval e env <+> eval e' env
```

Comment: I think your type signature for `Env` scopes `a` wrongly: I think the type you've given is equivalent to `Env : VerifiedMonoid a => (b : Type) -> Nat -> Type`. Also, what does the `VerifiedMonoid` constraint on `Env` supposed to buy you? If you remove it from `Env`'s signature, your code typechecks.

Answer (score 1):

As @Cactus mentioned in a comment, the problem here is that the type signature for `Env` is not correct.  Specifically, since the constraint is on the value of the argument, it is a dependent (pi) type, and Idris enforces that dependent types go left-to-right (be introduced before they are used).  My understanding is that basically the compiler will see the argument `x : a` as being shorthand for [image: \Pi_{(x\;:\;a)}B(x)], where [image: B(x)] is the part of the type signature to the right of the quantifier.  This means that `(a : Type)` actually binds a fresh `a`, which is not the same `a` that was used in the `VerifiedMonoid a` constraint (which is implicitly universally bound).

Luckily, since Idris isn't Haskell (where all type class constraints must be at the head of the type signature), this is easy to fix: just change your type signature to `Env : (a : Type) -> VerifiedMonoid a => Nat -> Type`, so that `a` is bound before it is used!